# Read chinese document in Cantonese instead of Mandarin in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, text-to-speech, chinese

Before July 2022, the Microsoft word "Read Aloud" function will read all "Chinese Hong Kong SAR" documents in Cantonese. However, after July 2022, all documents in "Chinese Hong Kong SAR" is read in Mandarin when using the same function. I have enabled the auto-update function of Microsoft Word and not sure if this is due to any version updated in my environment. Is there any way that we can change this back?